# HMACSHA1 oauth_signature in java

Tags: java, hmacsha1, signpost, oauth-1.0a

Is It possible to generate `HMACSHA1` oauth_signature in java without using `OAuthConsumer` of `signpost` library, so it can be easily implemented with other languages like `objective-c` etc?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since `HMACSHA1` is a standard you can write your own implementation.

[This is a gist with an example](https://gist.github.com/ishikawa/88599)

[Here a gist with Objective-c example](https://gist.github.com/tistaharahap/1202963)

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. can you tell me what would be the data as a parameter in 'calculateRFC2104HMAC()' method in the above first example. I am curious about the parameter 'data'.

Comment: The parameter `data` is the message that you want to encrypt.

You can take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

This is the [HMAC spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2104).

But in your code what you need to inform depends of what are you doing.
This is a [tutorial](http://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html) of how to sign a request using OAuth1.

Comment: can you please tell me how would i generate signature base string so that can i be sent it as a parameter in method.

Comment: Could you describe the kind of system are you trying to develop and what service are you trying to connect ?

Comment: I am trying to make request of request_token api using OAuth1.0

Comment: Here is the [twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token) to request the request_token.
I hope it will help you